# removeEventListener only removing single instance

Tags: javascript, removeeventlistener

I've been having issues where when I try to remove an event from the buttons it seems to only be removing the event for the one-button even though I have looped through the buttons and removed the event.

thank you.

```
function ChangeQuestions() {
    let currentQuestion = getQuestion(); //another function to get the question from an array - returns an object with questions, answers and correctAnswer
    const correctAnswer = currentQuestion.correct;
    console.log(currentQuestion);
    if (questionsArray.length === 0) {
        //If the array is empty push the questions again
        questionsArray.push(firstQuestion, secondQuestion, thirdQuestion);
    }
    document.querySelector('.question-header').textContent = currentQuestion.questions;
    for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        document.querySelector('.btn-Ans-' + i).textContent = currentQuestion.answers[i - 1];
        document.querySelector('.btn-Ans-' + i).addEventListener('click', function checkAns(e) {
            if (e.target.innerHTML === correctAnswer) {
                score++;
                console.log(score);
                removeEvent('click', checkAns);
                ChangeQuestions();
            } else {

                console.log(score);
                removeEvent('click', checkAns);
                ChangeQuestions();
            }
        });
    }
}


function removeEvent(event, func) {
    for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        document.querySelector('.btn-Ans-' + i).removeEventListener(event, func);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  document.querySelector('.btn-Ans-' + i).addEventListener('click', function checkAns(e) {
```

A new `checkAns` function is created *inside every iteration* of the loop, and `removeEventListener` must be passed *the exact same function* that `addEventListener` was called with. Since the different loop iterations have different functions passed into their respective `addEventListener` calls, the `removeEvent` function appears to only affect the element that was clicked, and none of the rest.

Here's a more minimal example:

```js
const fns = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  const foo = () => console.log('foo');
  fns.push(foo);
  window.addEventListener('click', foo);
}

// Not the same function:
console.log(fns[0] === fns[1]);
```

I'd add just a *single* listener to the container instead, and use event delegation to check which element was clicked on:

```
btnContainer.addEventListener('click', function handler(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('[class^="btn-Ans"]')) {
    return;
  }
  btnContainer.removeEventListener('click', handler);
  if (e.target.innerHTML === correctAnswer) {
    score++;
  }
  console.log(score);
  ChangeQuestions();
});
```

where `btnContainer` is a container for your `btn-Ans-`s.

Comment: Hi, I understand your approach but how does the .matches line work? I am not too sure how to implement it.

Comment: That's event delegation - add an event listener to the container, and when the event fires on the container, look at the target element to see if it's a child element you want to detect clicks on. That's what the `matches` does. If it matches, then proceed with the rest of your function.